# Hyper Threading OFF on PREEMPT RT Kernel 3.10.103-rt114

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos7, hyperthreading, preempt-rt

I have a Kernel compilation related issue where after successfull compilation and reboot 
HyperThreading option is lost. I am trying to update my Cent OS 7 vanilla kernel with PREEMPT RT kernel.

This is my first trial or experiment with Kernel.

The default kernel has version :- 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
Replacing it with :- 3.10.103-rt114

while in the image below on default kernel I can see HT enabled using i7z tool and lscpu says Nodes 2 and cores = 16

[Default Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIsPA.png)

but on RT Kernel HT is off lscpu says shows Node 1 and core 8.

[RT Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZAj9.png)

Please help I want RT to run with HT and one more help is required. I have compiled the RT kernel many time and thus there are many emtries as "Old ". Help me removing these too.

Comment: Both links point to the **same image**. `I have compiled the RT kernel ` - Have you enabled HT when **configured** the kernel?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Images updated. By RT Kernel I mean to have downloaded and used patch for the kernel as said in this [link](https://www.osadl.org/fileadmin/dam/interface/docbook/howtos/kernel-rt.pdf)

Comment: After patching, you should configure RT kernel (see 2.2.3 until `make` and  `make modules_install install`). Check value of option `SCHED_SMT` in the file `.config`.

Comment: The CONFIG_SCHED_SMT is set to "y"

Comment: @Tsyvarev please help i really need the solution. If you require I can send you the complete .config detail. I am doing this for first time and am unable to get any update on the topic from google.

Comment: It looks like kernel fails to autodetect that CPU supports HT. I don't know why. Probably, someone else who will visit the question may help.